# Angular fs.ReadFile cannot find the file with absolute path, nor can I compile the path with path.resolve

Tags: angular, typescript, path, node.js-fs, xml2js

I'm using my angular frontend to connect to a dymo labelprinter. The current setup, I have the entire xml file as a string inside an object. Than a parse it to json, let my code do changes based on the product, reconvert to xml and send it to the labelprinter.

I wanted to make this work better by moving my object containing a giant string with the xml, to a separate label.xml file. I'm having trouble with "finding" this file. To parse the file I am using [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js). I'm trying to use the function described under the title 'Simple as pie usage' to read in the xml file. I copied the example below:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
xml2js = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/foo.xml', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        console.dir(result);
        console.log('Done');
    });
});
```

First I tried it with the absolute path, which as I understood it, should definitly work on my local machine. But I kept getting an error in the browser "unresolved promise - Cannot find file". If checked countless times that I wasn't making mistakes in the path. But this wasn't the issue.
I found relevant topics on this matter on a similar function in `fs.readFileSync()`.

- [topic 1
  SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600943/fs-readfilesync-is-not-file-relative-node-js)
- [topic 2
  SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66737012/cannot-read-whole-file-through-fs-readfile-in-nodejs)
- [topic 3
  SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68502191/determining-the-path-in-fs-readfile)
- [topic 4
  Github](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/1326)

When I understand these topics corrects, fs.readFile will not work with an absolute path, and it always needs relative path. But since it is in different working directory, I need to use path.resolve() to set up the right path.

I'm not 100% sure I'm using it right, but when I use the path.resolve(), the console gives an error when going over this line of code:`path.resolve is not a function`. This is the code going on to retrieve the label.xml file:

```
const path = require("path");
var fs = require('fs'),
xml2js = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
  fs.readFile(path.resolve("src/assets", '../label.xml'), function(err: any, data: any) {
      parser.parseString(data, function (err: any, result: any) {
          console.dir(result);
          console.log('Done');
      });
  });
```

the absolute paths to my component and my label.xml are are:

```
  //absolute path to current ts file :  /c/Users/MyUsername/OneDrive/Documenten/Projects/ProjectName/src/app/components/componentName/componentName.ts
  //absolute path to label.xml file : '/c/Users/MyUsername/OneDrive/Documenten/Projects/ProjectName/src/assets/label.xml'
```

I would like to know why my angular is unable to use `path.resolve()`. I also went through a lot of documentation, but I don't know that fixing that function would solve the problem, because `fs.ReadFile()` also doesn't work with an absolute path. As stated I am not sure weather I'm correct that this functions needs a relative path to work. Can I get help on how to implement this function with my personal paths?

Maybe it is not due to the code, but there is a problem with the xml2js dependency? Beacuse I have to install it with `--legacy-peer-deps`. But I have this with a lot of dependencies because I'm using angular15 now. To be complete, I also added my package.json below. I don't think the issue has something to do with this.

```
{
  "name": "MyProjectName",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^9.0.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@types/dymo-label-framework": "^1.2.36",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "fs-web": "^1.0.1",
    "mdb-angular-ui-kit": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "url": "^0.11.3",
    "xml2js": "^0.6.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.0.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using "fs" and "path" in the browser? Both of those are not usable in the browser. If you are trying to read an xml file from angular, you can check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59357577

Comment: I am trying to check the behavior in the browser indeed.

Comment: But If I would put my program online, the behaviour would be on the server.

Comment: The answer of the link does not work. I tried that before.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to use this:

```
const path = require("path");
var fs = require('fs'),
```

in a browser?

Comment: I'm trying to test it in the browser yes. How could I test it If I don't use the browser?

Answer (score 0):

One part of the question has been answered by V.S. that it is not possible to use/test path on the browser. The link he provides is angular 8 and it does not work anymore for Angular 14. But I found a way to make it work in Angular 14.

First I managed to get the result by subscribing it, like this:

```
getXmlFile(){
return this.http.get("/assets/label.xml", {responseType : "text"});
 }

this.getXmlFile().subscribe((data: any)=>{
      let parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
      parseString(data, (err: any,result: any) =>{
        this.labelJson = result;
    });
});
```

But since I need the data in a variable for action. I made the function async.

```
async getXmlFileASync(){
    const responseObservable = this.http.get("/assets/label.xml", {responseType : "text"});
    return await firstValueFrom(responseObservable);
  }

const labelXml = await getXmlFileASync();

parseString(labelXml , (err: any,result: any) =>{
    console.log(result);
});
```

You could also make the parseString asynchronous if you would need it in a variable, because if you would insert it in an object directly, the object would be empty. I don't need that in this case.